# Aggregate query to get all different condition at single query in mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb

A document in my mongodb collection is as follows:

```
{
  "transaction_id": "e10cc8d64204394cd35329a88dc4ab8f",
  "timestamp": "2021-05-11 17:47:50",
  "client_id": "chae@aklas.kr",
  "ip": "172.69.34.31",
  "level": "OK",
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "status_code": 200,
    "status_name": "Ok",
    "url": "/ocr/driver"
  },
  "bytes": 297,
  "message": "Status authenticated successfully"
},
{
  "transaction_id": "e10cc8d64204394cd35329a88dc4ab8f",
  "timestamp": "2021-05-11 17:47:50",
  "client_id": "chae@kkk.kr",
  "ip": "172.69.34.31",
  "level": "OK",
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "status_code": 200,
    "status_name": "Ok",
    "url": "/status/driver"
  },
  "bytes": 297,
  "message": "Status authenticated successfully"
}......
```

I can get the total of each request.url by timestamp(daily-based) with the following query.

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([ 
    {
       $match: { 
            client_id: { $regex : '^chae@'}, 
           'request.url': { $regex : '^\/ocr'}}
    },
    { '$group' :
        {
            '_id': { $substr: [ "$timestamp", 0, 10 ] },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        '$sort':
            { 'count': -1}
     }
])
```

then I get the result of request.url in which contains /^ocr/

```
_id        |  count
2021-10-01 |  10
2021-09-30 |  15
2021-09-29 |  11
....
```

It seems ok. However if I want to get a different request.url, I have to send another query.
Can I do get the result of all different request.url at a time with one single query?

My desired outcome is something like this.

```
_id        |  count(ocr) | count(status) | count(something else)
2021-10-01 |  10         | 20            | 56 
2021-09-30 |  15         | 26            | 28 
2021-09-29 |  11         | 87            | 466
```

I even don't know if it's possible in mongodb?
Please advise me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- group accepts expression also, so we can calculate the group value
- here we have 2 group keys
- those that their email starts with chae and url with /ocr
- those that their email starts with chae and url with /status
- we sum those seperatly
- if you add more cases on the `$switch` you can do this for many different searches
- if you dont know those cases when you write the query, you need to contruct this `{"$switch" ...}` dynamically you can do it with a loop, its easy to do, loop on the variables and create it
- if you have an index on those fields, you can add a `$match` on top, like allow only
  `(or (chae and /ocr) (chae and /status) ...)`

There is also a `$facet` solution (facet = 1 aggregation per field)

- if index is used on the $match , $facet or $group similar perfomance (you do regex match so test the index use), but $facet simpler query
- if not index, `$facet` will do 1 collection scan per field, so go
  for the `$group` i think

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49ab)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": 
     {"reg": 
       {"$switch": 
         {"branches": 
           [{"case": 
              {"$and": 
                [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$client_id", "regex": "^chae@"}},
                 {"$regexMatch": {"input": "$request.url", "regex": "^/ocr"}}]},
                "then": "chae-ocr"},
           {"case": 
             {"$and": 
               [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$client_id", "regex": "^chae@"}},
                {"$regexMatch": 
                  {"input": "$request.url", "regex": "^/status"}}]},
                "then": "chae-status"}],
            "default": "other"}},
        "time": {"$substrCP": ["$timestamp", 0, 10]}},
      "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
  {"$project": {"_id": "$_id.time", "count": 1, "searched": "$_id.reg"}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to get multiple results like this:

If you are using any programming language you can easily create the object for the query to not repeat code.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$facet": {
    "ocr": [
      // your query here
    ],
    "status": [
      // your query using $regex : '^\/status'
    ],
    "whatever":[
      // your query using $regex : '^\/whatever'
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hoe-rm0x5J7)

Comment: This seems exactly what I want. 
I rewrited the code according to your code sample in my code.  just changed json to array. but $facet doesn't work on my php code.